# Use two citations and text in \cite

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

I want to cite two authors that contradict each other. I tried the following:

```
\cite[~ contradicts ~]{AuthorA, AuthorB}
```

However this gives me [Author A, AuthorB but see]
I would like the following output: [Author A but see Author B]

Regarding the comments:
To be honest I'm not so sure about all this...
I don't explicitly load a package for citation, I think. These are the packages I use:

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}    
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

At the end of the document I add

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{File.bib}
```

Normally I cite like this `\cite{AuthorYEAR}` which gives for example [1]

Comment: `\cite{A} contradicts \cite{B}`?

Comment: @Johannes_B: This gives [AuthorA] contradicts [AuthorB], which is not what I want (i.e. not what the Journal wants)

Comment: We have absolutely no idea, how you are [creating your references](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies).

Comment: Please tell us whether you use BibTeX or biblatex. Assuming you use BibTeX, please also tell us which bibliography style you employ, which citation management package (if any) you use, and how you generate citation call-outs.

Comment: @Johannes_B, @ Mico: I tried to answer your questions. Thanks for your help